# google cloud app engine to postgresql connection refused

Tags: java, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application to google cloud app engine. I used below command to deploy

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

It seems deploy successful but when I observe logs db connection refused. Shows below error in logs

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection
>   timed out) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121] at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121] at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121] at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121] at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121] at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121] at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121] at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121] at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121] at
>   org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:62)
>   ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar!/:na] at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76)
>   ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar!/:na]

Can some one help to resolve the issue?

Comment: `Connection timed out` as is shown in the logs, not refused. Most likely a firewall blocking your packets. Be sure you have allowed connections from your IP.

Comment: @MattClark thanks for your time. I am using google cloud app engine and postgres db on google cloud. I even added ip address of my instances to authorized network of db. But it did not help

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into the issue.

Using Google App Engine in standard environment, following [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine#connecting_the_standard_environment_to), I was getting Connection Refused constantly.

It turns out that App Engine is using the Cloud SQL proxy under the hood, and that means your Cloud SQL instance must have a **public IP address**.

As soon as I activated this on my instance, it worked.